# How do I convert a .doc or .xls under TFS source control to .docx or .xlsx?

Tags: version-control, tfs

I have a number of Word Documents (.doc) and Excel Workbooks (.xls) under source control in TFS.

How do I convert these to .docx or .xlsx without losing the TFS history, in a single check-in?

Answer (score 2):

Using "Excel 2013" and "Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web" as an example:

1. Check out from TFS and open your XLS in Excel.
2. In Excel, click File, choose the Info tab, and click the Convert button. Exit and Save.
3. Your local copy is now a real XLSX file, both format and extension. The old XLS is deleted.
4. Open Source Control Explorer -> Pending Changes in Visual Studio Express.
5. In the Excluded Changes section, choose the Detected: link. It will show the XLS as Deleted and XLSX as Added.
6. In the Promote Candidate Changes dialog box, select the delete and add actions, open their shortcut menu, and choose Promote as Rename.
7. A single rename change now appears in the Included Changes section.
8. Check in your pending change. Done!

The process is similar for Word DOC files.

Note - steps 5, 6, 7 are copied from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/rename-move-files-folders